# Css getting applied to all pages in angular primeng

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I am using p-dropdown & have applied min-width to p-dropdown panel in two different pages.

In page1 css

```
.p-dropdown panel {
  min-width: 35% !important;
  }
```

In page2 css

```
.p-dropdown panel {
  min-width: 20% !important;
 }
```

When I open page2 after opening page1, then page1 css for p-dropdown panel is getting applied.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in page2 css.

```
.p-dropdown panel {
  min-width: 20% !important
 }
```

Comment: I have applied !important in both css, it is taking page1 css and this might be just workaround solution, what if I have more pages with p-dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your entire css/project - in Chrome you can open up Dev Tools, select the element, and view the "Computed" tab to look up what file/css is determining the width.